# Describe the singularity of $\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ near $(x,y) = (0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, singularity-theory

in calculus class we are shown the function $ f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} $ is not $C^\infty$ at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.  However if we exclude the origin, we can define a surface:

$$  \left\{  \left( x,y,\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}\right) : (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{ (0,0)\} \right\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R} $$

What kind of singularity does this surface have at the origin?  I have been looking up different names but they are too technical:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_Val_singularity
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_singularity
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_theory

Locally near the origin we could consider $(x,y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ and our map looks like:

$$ (x,y) \mapsto \frac{{\color{#AAA}{r^2}} \sin \theta \cos \theta}{{\color{#AAA}{r^2}}} = \frac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta $$

so as long as $r \neq 0$ there is a well-defined surface.  Is there an algebraic model for this kind of singularity?

Comment: So you weren't given a definition of singularity?

Comment: @GitGud This is not a homework problem.  it's up to us to figure out a definition of "singularity".  I give a few suggestions from Wikipedia. At the very least, we have that the limit doesn't exist near the origin.

Comment: Since any curve or sequence approaching the singularity has $\liminf \ge -\frac 12$ and $\limsup \le \frac 12$, I would describe it as "bounded".

Comment: Usually “singular point” means a point *on* a variety where the tangent space is ill-defined. So perhaps you should define the surface not by $z=xy/(x^2+y^2)$ but by $z(x^2+y^2)-xy=0$, so that the point $(0,0,0)$ actually belongs to the surface. But then, on the other hand, you will include the whole $z$ axis too, so the set will look like the union of a surface and a line... (Unfortunately I don't know much algebraic geometry, so I have no idea of what the name for this kind of situation might be.)